# How should Interfaces and Abstract mthods be used?

Tags: oop, interface, abstract-methods

**Are Interfaces and Abstract Methods really just used to ensure Developers include those methods in their classes??**

Couldn`t this also be achieved by using a process? e.g test driven development.

It seems to be inflexible. What happens when the code changes?

I am struggling to understand the need for these restrictions. 
 Why even add an Interface in the code when it has the potential to make more work in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You usually use interfaces or abstract classes to decouple two concrete classes from each other.

Let's have a look at the [MouseListener interface in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html), which allows you to track certain events like mouse clicks. This interface declares five methods:

```
void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e);
void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e);
void mouseExited(MouseEvent e);
void mousePressed(MouseEvent e);
void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e);
```

UI elements like buttons, text fields etc. (subclasses of [the abstract class Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)) allow you to register `MouseListener`s with the `addMouseListener` method.

The `Component` class probably contains code for detecting that the mouse moved inside a certain area and that the mouse button was pressed or released in that area. All subclasses of `Component` now benefit from that behaviour and do not have to implement this themselves.

Now there are a lot of things you can do with mouse events. You might want to change the color of something based on the mouse position, you might want to show or hide something base on mouse clicks, .... There's an infinite list of things you could do with mouse events. So how should `Component` know what *you* want to do in one particular case?

But since you know what you want to do on mouse events of a given `Component`, it allows you to register a `MouseListener` that it will call when the above mentioned events happen. And since you implement the `MouseListener` you can do anything you want....

In this particular example interfaces are pretty flexible. Because even if you want to do something different on certain mouse events, you don't have to change the `Component` class. You *must* change your `MouseListener`, sure. But the implementation of `Component` remains the same for all the possible things that you might want to do with mouse events.

Hope that helps a bit...

---

### Update

Maybe the "problem" is that in some languages (like Java, C#, C++) you have to provide type information at compile time for the compiler to know which methods exist for a given object.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_and_dynamic_type_checking_in_practice):

> Statically typed languages that lack type inference (such as C and Java) require that programmers declare the types they intend a method or function to use.
>   This can serve as additional documentation for the program [...]

So I think that one could answer your question with **yes**, interfaces and abstract methods are used to ensure that developers include those methods in their classes, but only because in the above mentioned languages the compiler has no other means of determining whether method exists.

But one could also answer your question with **no** for the reasons I tried to explain above.

Tough one....

Comment: "UI elements like buttons, text fields etc. (subclasses of the "abstract class Component) allow you to register MouseListeners with the addMouseListener method."
What is the benefit of using the MouseListener Interface vs A custom made Mouse event Interface? I mean, an Interface only gives me a list of methods I must use. <br> Couldn`t I just write my own? I have to write the method behaviour anyways. I see it as inflexible because I must add a method even if I don`t want to use it..i am struggling on this one :) and do appreciate your help.

Comment: This may be true for languages like Python where it is determined at runtime whether you can call a method on a given object. In languages like Java this is determined at compile time. You introduce interfaces and abstract classes to describe abstract concepts. I.e. the authors of the `Component` class have no idea what you might do with the mouse events, but they tell you which methods they are going to call when you implement the `MouseListener` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer that satisfies my need to understand the use for interfaces in a working team.

I feel it is used in projects to ensure developers don`t write methods with similar names and create confusion.
Read **Chapter 8: Interfaces & Inner Classes from "Thinking in Java" Second Edition by Bruce Eckel**

I think it still remains true that Interfaces are not absolutely essential.
But is can be said about OOP, I could code Java a million different ways. Although, I choose to use OOP to minimize headaches.
However, if I am a working on another persons code, I can use the interface to find out
what other methods can be found in similar classes or even create methods that need to be created...etc

Here is an example from the book:

```
// Interfaces.
import java.util.*;
interface Instrument {
// Compile-time constant:
int i = 5; // static & final
// Cannot have method definitions:
void play(); // Automatically public
String what();
void adjust();
}

class Wind implements Instrument {
public void play() {
System.out.println("Wind.play()");
}
public String what() { return "Wind"; }
public void adjust() {}
}

class Percussion implements Instrument {
public void play() {
System.out.println("Percussion.play()");
}
public String what() { return "Percussion"; }
public void adjust() {}
}

class Stringed implements Instrument {
public void play() {
System.out.println("Stringed.play()");
}
public String what() { return "Stringed"; }
public void adjust() {}
}
```